# How to simplify Sum's and Product's of arbitrary length?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, summation, products

I would expect

```
Sum[Subscript[x,i], {i, 1, n}] + Sum[-Subscript[x,i], {i, 1, n}]
```

and

```
Product[Subscript[x,i], {i, 1, n}]*Product[Subscript[x,i]^-1, {i, 1, n}]]
```

to simplify to `0` and `1`, which they do not. The only way I was able to make them do so was when assuming `n == 9` or any other specific integer. But clearly they should do so for any integer (assuming they are integer doesn't help either; nor does assuming the `x`'s are finite).

How can I simplify Sum's and Product's for sequences of arbitrary length?

Comment: Consider `x[i_]:=RandomReal[]` or `x[i_]:=Infinity` or `x[i_]:=Indeterminant` How does Mathematica know these and other even stranger cases are not what the unknown abstract function x[i] and abstract sum are? Mathematica's handling of abstract vectors, sums, products, functions... is limited.

Comment: If these strange cases are an issue for an unspecified integer, why are they not then an issue when I specify the integer? Also `Simplify[...,ForAll[i,Element[x[i],Reals]]]` doesn't lead to a result for me.

Comment: @Bill Does using subscripts like now avoid the additional complication from the abstract functions?

Comment: It is guessing plus some evidence that the implementation of Mathematica is not strictly exactly correct in many border cases. That may be a tradeoff between ease of conventional use versus formal rigor. Subscripts have a history of problems. One example: I recently changed all `Subscript[b,i]` into `bi` in a differential equation that a person had been struggling with for days with no success and it magically worked. I always assume the more you desktop publish your input the more problems you are inviting. Google subscript problem site:mathematica.stackexchange.com and see what you find.

Comment: Thanks for your explanations. What I'm trying to find out is: given an unspecified sequence in the Reals, how can I simplify Sum's and Product's of it. If there's a better version to define the sequence, it would be helpful to have the question changed accordingly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
sumRule = 
  Sum[expr1_, iter_List] + Sum[expr2_, iter_List] :> 
   Sum[expr1 + expr2, iter];

productRule = 
  Product[expr1_, iter_List]*Product[expr2_, iter_List] :> 
   Product[expr1*expr2, iter];

Sum[Subscript[x, i], {i, 1, n}] + 
  Sum[-Subscript[x, i], {i, 1, n}] /. sumRule

(* 0 *)

Product[Subscript[x, i], {i, 1, n}]*
  Product[Subscript[x, i]^-1, {i, 1, n}] /. productRule

(* 1 *)
```

Comment: Do you think `sumRule = c1_ Sum[expr1_, iter_List] + c2_ Sum[expr2_, iter_List] :> Sum[c1 expr1 + c2 expr2, iter]` is a suitable generalization for cases when there are prefactors?

Comment: @ChrisK - almost. You need to include handling the defaults, i.e., `sumRule = c1_. Sum[expr1_, iter_List] + c2_. Sum[expr2_, iter_List] :> Sum[c1 expr1 + c2 expr2, iter]` Note the presence of the periods.

Comment: Excellent, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

```
rule1 = Sum[a_Times, b : {i_, __}] :> Select[FreeQ[i]][a] Sum[Select[Not@*FreeQ[i]][a], b]
rule2 = Product[Power[a_, b_.], c_] :> Product[a, c]^b;
```

***Examples:***

```
expr1 = Sum[Subscript[x, i], {i, 1, n}] + Sum[-Subscript[x, i], {i, 1, n}];

TeXForm @ expr1
```

> $\sum _{i=1}^n -x_i+\sum _{i=1}^n x_i$

```
expr1 /. rule1
```

> 0

```
expr2 = Product[Subscript[x, i], {i, 1, n}]*Product[Subscript[x, i]^-1, {i, 1, n}];

TeXForm @ expr2
```

> $\left(\prod _{i=1}^n \frac{1}{x_i}\right) \prod _{i=1}^n x_i$

```
expr2 /. rule2
```

> 1

Comment: What if the term includes more than one factor, e.g., `Sum[Subscript[x, i]*Subscript[y, i], {i, 1, n}] + 
  Sum[-Subscript[x, i]*Subscript[y, i], {i, 1, n}] /. rule1`

Comment: @Thank you @BobHanlon; very good point. I updated `rule1` with something that works for your example.