# Simple expression involing Sum[] Mathematica fails to simplify

Tags: simplifying-expressions, summation

I have been trying to coax Mathematica to solve some equations involving expressions like `Sum[A[t],t]`, with mixed success. One thing that really surprised me though is that it is unable to simplify something like

`Sum[A[t],t] + Sum[-A[t],t]`

`Simplify[]` of that returns the same expression, not the hoped for `0`.

Obviously, I am interesting in expressions a little more complicated that this one, but if even here it doesn't work those will be even more impossible.
Is there a trick of technique that will make it simplify the above expression to 0?

For instance, if I have a linear combination of `Sum`s of different expressions over the same variable, is there a nice way of rewritting that as the Sum of the linear combination?

Comment: Thanks @DiSp0sablE_H3r0, that was exactly what I was looking for, but I couldn't find that question myself. I think this should be marked as duplicate, not sure what the best way of doing that is. Should I just delete the question?

Comment: I wrote an extensive comment, that is hopefully a little bit helpful and can outline the logic a little bit. As far as I know, you should not delete the post. The mods will take care of it

Comment: Sorry. Don't know what happened and posted twice the same link...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is meant to be just an extensive comment, rather than an answer.

It requires some very minor modification of the [accepted answer here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/213086/how-to-simplify-sums-and-products-of-arbitrary-length) to make it work in this example.

Let us assume, that you do NOT want to modify the replacement rule from the link I posted. Hence, you have

```
sumRule1 = 
  Sum[expr1_, iter_List] + Sum[expr2_, iter_List] :> 
   Sum[expr1 + expr2, iter];
```

You can either truncate the sums at some arbitrary value, let's call it `i`, or make a list `{t}`. Hence you run

```
Sum[A[t], {t, i}] + Sum[-A[t], {t, i}] /. sumRule1
Sum[A[t], {t}] + Sum[-A[t], {t}] /. sumRule1
```

and both of the above yield zero.

In case you want to keep precisely the form of the sums that you have provided for practical reasons, then you can modify the replacement rule as follows:

sumRule2 =
Sum[expr1_, iter_] + Sum[expr2_, iter_] :> Sum[expr1 + expr2, iter];

Then, you run

```
Sum[A[t], t] + Sum[-A[t], t] /. sumRule2
```

which returns zero as well.